# I can't use my screen due to implementation of drawer

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working on an android studio project and I am trying to implement a side drawer/navigation to work through all pages in my app. Although I thought I had it working, when I run it I can slide open the drawer but I can't edit or remove or do anything on my mainactivity, it's as if the drawer page is just sitting over the top and I am unsure how to implement the drawer properly to use it on the side of each and every page I will use.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row"
    />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/addFabButton"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    />

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_nav.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="left" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I found that if I dont have both **widget.DrawerLayout** and **NavigationView** in both **activity_nav** and **activity_main** it won't show the drawer when I run it.

Any help or tips will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at your `activity_nav` setup. That's how `activity_main` should be; the `<DrawerLayout>` as the root, with two direct children, the first being the main content, and the second being the drawer.

Comment: That works thankyou, although when I do all of that, my floatingactionbutton id/addFabButton grows to an enourmous size and covers the middle of my screen?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have it inside the main content. Any `View` that is a direct child of `DrawerLayout` that is not a drawer will be laid out to `match_parent` in both directions, regardless of what you've set in the XML.